# Hyperbolic disks in AdS/CFT

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesics, ads-cft

The embedding of AdS space into Minkowski spacetime describes a hyperboloid as e.g. shown in the corresponding Wikipedia article on AdS space. Now my questions are:

1. How does this relate to the visualisation that is usually used in AdS/CFT, where AdS space is represented as "stacks" of hyperbolic disks?
2. Do the arcs on these slices represent certain type of geodesics? And how do we obtain their description?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the AdS spacetime is not embedded into Minkowski spacetime. Instead, it is embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2,d}$, whose isometry group is the conformal group $O(2,d)$.

1. For your first question, the usual visualization of the $AdS$ spacetime is actually not the $AdS$ manifold itself, but the universal covering of the $AdS$ manifold. An $AdS_{n}$ manifold has the product topology of $\mathbb{S}\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. It's universal covering space has the topology of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Here, $\mathbb{R}$ is the time direction, and $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is the spatial slice.

To be specific, for example, the metric of the universal coverering of global $AdS_{3}$ is given by $$ds^{2}=-\cosh^{2}\rho dt^{2}+\sinh^{2}\rho d\theta^{2}+d\rho^{2}.$$

For a constant $t$, the spatial slice of the above metric gives the metric of the [Poincare disk model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model), which is a model of two-dimensional [hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry). Hyperbolic geometry is the Euclidean version of the $AdS$ geometry. It has maximal symmetries and negative constant scalar curvature. When you Wick-rotate the $AdS$ metric into the Euclidean signature, you end up with a hyperbolic manifodl. This means that the universal covering space of an $n$-dimensional global $AdS$ spacetime looks like stacks (in the time direction) of $n-1$ dimensional (Euclidean) Poincare balls.

2. Yes. Arcs that are perpendicular to the conformal boundary (at infinity) of the Poincare disks are geodesics in Poincare balls. In the global $AdS$ spacetimes, they are space-like geodesics.